# SKStoreReviewController : How do I know user has rated the app to avoid alert in Future?

Tags: ios10.3, skstorereviewcontroller

Here is the reference API:

```
[SKStoreReviewController requestReview];
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't Apple does it automatically for you, up to 3 times per year max I think. I guess the rule is 'do not ask again if it's the same version' otherwise ask again for new version.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I detect if the `skstorereviewcontroller` has been presented: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45329548/2589276

However this does not guarantee that the user has rated the app. It doesn't matter anyways, Apple is only going to allow you to show 3 times regardless if the user rated or clicked "Later"