# Detect if SKStoreReviewController has displayed app rating window on macOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-mojave, skstorereviewcontroller

The way to ask for review

```
SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
```

On iOS folks found pretty easy way how to find if rating window has been presented [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268014/is-it-possible-determine-if-skstorereviewcontroller-has-been-presented) (just by counting number of windows within the app)

How to reliably detect this on macOS? (Counting windows alternatives?)

[image: Store]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found that `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` + NSRunningApplication are the right things to inspect:

```
dispatch_time_t twoSecondsFromNow = DISPATCH_TIME_NOW + 2.0;
dispatch_after(twoSecondsFromNow, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    //HERE REQUEST REVIEW
    [SKStoreReviewController requestReview];

    dispatch_time_t secondFromNow = DISPATCH_TIME_NOW + 1.0;
    dispatch_after(secondFromNow, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
        NSArray <NSString*>*windowNames = [(__bridge NSArray *)windowList valueForKey:@"kCGWindowOwnerName"];
        CFRelease(windowList);
        if ([windowNames containsObject:@"storeuid"]) {

            //REPORT TO PREFERENCES THAT WE SUCCESSFULLY ASKED FOR REVIEW
            NSLog(@"Rating Window was presented");
        }
    });
});
```

Possible alternative (as of 10.14.2 with significant delays for deactivations) :

```
- (void)findRunningApplication
{
    NSArray<NSRunningApplication *> *runningApplications = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
    for (NSRunningApplication *app in runningApplications) {
        if ([[app bundleIdentifier] isEqualToString:@"com.apple.storeuid"]) {
            [self setRunningApplication:app];
        }
    }
}

- (void)setRunningApplication:(NSRunningApplication *)runningApplication
{
    if (runningApplication != _runningApplication) {

        if (runningApplication == nil) {
            [_runningApplication removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"active"];
        } else {
            [runningApplication addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"active" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:StoreInspectorKVOContext];
        }
        _runningApplication = runningApplication;
    }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == StoreInspectorKVOContext) {
        if (object == [self runningApplication] && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"active"]) {
            [self runningApplicationActiveHasChanged];
        }
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}
```

One can even get what rating has user clicked with global monitor event + position from cgwindow

```
NSEvent *monitor = [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMaskLeftMouseDown)
                                                          handler:^(NSEvent *event) {
                                                              NSLog(@"%@",event);
                                                          }];



2019-01-13 23:58:12.727979+0100 testWindows2[11466:620853] NSEvent: type=LMouseDown loc=(994.746,172.551) time=103867.3 flags=0 win=0x0 winNum=4852 ctxt=0x0 evNum=9320 click=1 buttonNumber=0 pressure=1 deviceID:0x300000014400000 subtype=NSEventSubtypeTouch
2019-01-13 23:58:12.729521+0100 testWindows2[11466:620853] {
    kCGWindowAlpha = 1;
    kCGWindowBounds =     {
        Height = 157;
        Width = 420;
        X = 786;
        Y = 23;
    };
    kCGWindowIsOnscreen = 1;
    kCGWindowLayer = 0;
    kCGWindowMemoryUsage = 1248;
    kCGWindowNumber = 4590;
    kCGWindowOwnerName = storeuid;
    kCGWindowOwnerPID = 7017;
    kCGWindowSharingState = 1;
    kCGWindowStoreType = 1;
}
```

Comment: One possible solution that I haven't played with is :[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] and addObserver for NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification NSWorkspaceDidUnhideApplicationNotification NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification. User info of the delivered notification should contain some information.